# how to import bytea column in postgres 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Team,

I have a table1 which is having 2 columns col1 bigint and col2 bytea
Need to take one record of the table1 and restored into different machine of table2. Both table1 and table2 having same structure.

I have tried following steps but its throwing exception.
step1) taken single record backup into a CSV file.
step2) tried to importing CSV file into a table2 by usinf COPY command

ERROR: unsupported format bytea.
Could anyone help me out of this.

Thanks

Comment: I dont recall such exception in postgres... is it psycopg2 by incident?..

Comment: suggest me if there is other way which i can resolve ?

Comment: resolve what?.. please elaborate your post with code samples and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PGSQL [COPY Command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-copy.html) to export and also import the table in binary format.